# catch and send sse stream using Python

Tags: python-3.x, request, server-sent-events

I want to create an Azure function app catch request from Apim and send this request to Azure OpenAi. I already create an app working in normal mode, but I don't know how to make it work with stream mode (sse).
This is my code:

```
def request_change2(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

url = 'https://xxxxxx'  
header = {}
header['api-key'] = 'xxxxxxxx'
header['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
data = req.get_json()
response = requests.request(
    method='POST',
    url=url,
    headers=header,
    json=data,
    params=params)

def generate():
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
        if chunk: yield chunk
        
return func.HttpResponse(
    generate, 
    mimetype='text/event-stream'
)
```